# Callbacks and Functions with arguments

Tags: jquery

I am calling a function using get method of ajax. Actually after searching on net i found a approach!! 
  My function  in fetch.aspx is:

```
  public string GetData(string user)
  {



 }
```

So for calling this function i wrote a $.Get which is:

```
 $.get("Fetch.aspx", function (data) {
                    GetData(user);
                    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                });
```

so here how can i pass parameters in Get method?
          GetData(user:'"somevalue"');
 Is this correct?

Comment: `public string GetData(string user)`??? in JavaScript, You should learn some basic first. Start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: that is giving me null everytime!!

Comment: @Satpal that is not javascript man!! It is function of fetch.aspx

Comment: comment mistakes before downvoting!!

Comment: You have only tagged with jQuery. You should also tag properly. Just for record I have not downvoted

Comment: GetData({"user":"somevalue"})

Answer (score 0):

Method: we must use web method for ajax calls (Fetch.aspx.cs)

```
[WebMethod]
public static void GetData(string user)
{

}
```

Jquery: You have to USe POST to pass a parameters

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Fetch.aspx/GetData",
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: "{ 'user': 'someValue' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (jsonObj) {
       alert(sucess);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert(fail);
    }
});
```

Comment: you did nt understood what i want!! i am clearly mentioned there i want to get results from a function using $.Get

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

You should use the Web Method attribute:

ASP.NET Code:

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet=true)]
public static string GetData(string user)
{
    /*You can do database operations here if required*/
    return "hello  " + user;
}
```

The $.get is just a shorthand method for $.ajax, more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). However, to call a Web Method in web forms, you need to specify the `contentType="application/json; charset=utf-8"`, which you cannot do with the $.get.

Also, to send parameters in a GET request, you must specify them in the query string - like this:`Fetch.aspx/GetData?user='chavakane'`

Another thing, jquery caches by default the responses of GET requests, you can turn it off but I recommend using GET requests only for loading stuff.

Javascript/JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Fetch.aspx/GetData?user='chavakane'",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) { alert(data.d);}
});
```

Comment: your method will hit in the debug with out using [webmethod], my approach works!! But the problem here is with the parameter we are sending. In your approach also it is not giving me value"12345" its giving null

Comment: I corrected my answer, take a look a it. To pass parameters into a GET request they must be included in the query string.